# Using 'this' reference to actual element in Angular forms

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

Is possible to reference actual DOM element in an angular form like raw javascript works?

Example:
I have a form with input field:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="anInputField" />
</form>
```

Then somewhere in my code I set up a new attribute for the input field element

```
$scope.myForm.anInputField.newAttribute = 'abc';
```

After that I need to pass this value to a custom directive, something like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="anInputField" 
           custom-directive="{{ myForm.anInputField.newAttribute }}"/>
</form>
```

This works, but I always need to use the whole path to that element in the form (`myForm.anInputField.newAttribute`). I have a very complex form, with large number of subforms, which are generated via `ng-repeat`. So using full paths is not acceptable (in this case, I need to know all the indices of all subforms generated by `ng-repeat`). I would like to use something like `custom-directive="{{ this.newAttribute }}`, but in this context `this` is reference to current scope. How can I get reference to current element?

Comment: No, it's not possible to access input like this in your case. What does customDirective do?